# SB Admin 2 Sidebar Not collapsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, django

[image]

Ok so I am trying to load sb-admin-2 and the menu is not collapsing, I browsed for some solutions and none of them work for me, also as you can see the data-table is not working too and my tags looks like this:

> 

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{STATIC_URL}}/static/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{STATIC_URL}}/static/lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{STATIC_URL}}/static/lib/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{STATIC_URL}}/static/lib/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{STATIC_URL}}/static/lib/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{STATIC_URL}}/static/lib/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{STATIC_URL}}/static/lib/angular-ui-validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{STATIC_URL}}/static/lib/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{STATIC_URL}}/static/lib/ng-file-upload-shim.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{STATIC_URL}}/static/lib/ng-file-upload.min.js"></script>

<!--SB ADMIN FILES-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{STATIC_URL}}/static/lib/metisMenu.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{STATIC_URL}}/static/lib/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{STATIC_URL}}/static/lib/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{STATIC_URL}}/static/lib/dataTables.responsive.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{STATIC_URL}}/static/lib/sb-admin-2.min.js"></script>
```

can you help me out guys.

ps: I am loading sb-admin through angularjs and django

Answer (score 1):

gentos - i had a similar issue (sidebar not collapsing) and it turned out that i had overlapping jquery's.  Once i removed the calls to both jquery and jquery.min files and just used a jquery link:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
```

collapsible sidebar returned.  I also reordered jquery and put the above link at the top of my HTML file (above bootstrap, metisMenu, etc.)

Comment: @buburwell thanks my friend, the problem was at AngularJs. I had to lazy load the scripts because when route changes the sidebar script not fired